# Bricked Vodafone smart 2 (Alcatel V860)

Tags: boot, boot-loop, fastboot

I accidentally erased boot and bootloader. download mode nor recovery works and my pc recognize it like Broadcom USB. Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

here is a tutorial how to fix your alcatel

the tutorial is a video on youtube its in spanish but dont worry i fixed mine
even thoght i dont understand spanish

ok here is the video link

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxZYcs6mSMA

and here is the files you need to fix your phone
https://www.mediafire.com/?gyhxb15ojb6dq6t
try to watch the video first
after you download the file unzip it to your desktop
first thing you need to do is to shutdown your phone remove the battery and put the battery back into your phone press and hold the VOLUME UP button and turn on your phone then connect your phone to pc using the usb cable
now open the folder you unziped to your desktop and double click Romeo.cmd
now you can see som thing like this[image: Romeo home screen]
type 1 and hit Enter once you see  press any key to return to home
type 2 and hit enter again ......do that for all rest steps
once you reach the 7 step your phone will restart unplug your phone from usb cable dont worry if it looks un usual 
now try to enter recovery mode and select recover user data
once done reboot your phone and enjoy
I hope this was helpfull

Answer (score -1):

When a thing like that happens you need to install the driver "Broadcom Usb to Serial" and you need to use SPFlash tool with the correct scatter file for your model .
Scatter file includes the addresses for all the partitions in the phone memory , like boot , bootloader , recover , data , system ,etc ..
The Scatter file have the Hex addresses of each partition and its size .
Here you can find the driver : 
(Note: This driver is for windows XP 32bit , it does ot work in 7 or later , create a VM for this )

http://www.mediafire.com/file/phbd8epz92u6dw2/Broadcom_smartphone_USB_Driver.zip

The firmware you can find it here , download the stock rom Eglish:
https://github.com/peterpt/Alcatel_V860_smart_2/tree/master/Roms

SPflash tool ca n be downloaded here :
https://spflashtool.com/

Now the most important thing (Scatter file) i am unable to get it for you because i am also looking for it :) .

Let me know if you find it .
The manual in how to do all the process can be found here : 
https://www.gogorapid.com/flash-stock-rom-alcatel-v860/

Comment: Mediafire links aren't useful because they expire after a short time. Do you have a link to an official, trustworthy download for this file?